# Send multiple parameters in link?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send multiple objects in link and be able to get them in my server side.
Currently I am trying this:

```
<a href="?page={{ page }}+?filter={{data.sort}}">{{ page }}</a>
```

The result I get with console.log(req.query):

```
GET /products?filterlist=price-high 200 96.523 ms
{ page: '2 ?filter=price-high' }
```

Is it possible to get object with two (or multiple) parameters?

```
{ page: '2', filter: 'price-high' }
```

Comment: you have to use `&` to separate parameters `?page={{page}}&filter={{filter}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in multiple parameters in the following manner -

`products?filterlist=price-high&abc=def`

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that nodejs has special symbol in link: "&"
So now if we assign this symbol in the link:

```
<a href="?page={{ page }}&filter={{data.sort}}">{{ p }}</a>
```

The result I get in req.query is:

```
{ page: '2', filter: 'price-high' }
```

Comment: "that nodejs has special symbol in link" — That is standard URL syntax and has been since before JavaScript existed. It isn't anything special for node.